# Is there a way to communicate with the Isabelle theorem prover through python?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I want to build a python API for Isabelle. I was wondering if it's possible? Is it possible to send proofs, tactics, command and all that jedit would be doing through Python and type check the proofs?

Comment: Pretty sure no. You could take a look at how Lars Hupel's libisabelle does it; this is a similar problem but with Scala instead of Python: https://github.com/larsrh/libisabelle

Comment: @ManuelEberl why is it not possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't really read your question properly. I thought you asked whether something like that already existed. It's certainly /possible/, although I fear it will be quite a lot of work and require getting a lot into Isabelle internals. The easiest approach is probably to communicate with the Isabelle/Scala process, which is, I think, what libisabelle does.

Comment: Another option is to communicate via the LSP protocol.